# Get "previous" and "next" buttons on view

Tags: 7, views

The view I want to create consists of two parts:

1. An overview page with all the products, that is sortable using Draggable Views.
   The url given by /collection/
2. A specific page that is shown when a user clicks on a product in the overview.
   The url given by /collection/[title]

Now I want prev / next buttons on the product page, based on the order given by Draggable Views.

I've searched for a couple of hours but cannot find anything that will do the trick. Can someone point me at an option or function that accomplishes this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Drupal/Views version?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7 with Views 7.x-3.0-rc3, Draggable Views 7.x-1.x-dev

Comment: I am in the exact same situation, have you found any solution to that?

Comment: Maybe you could use http://drupal.org/project/prev_next to get some solution, though i wouldn't count this as answer.

Answer (score 2):

This module might be able to do the trick [Views navigation](https://drupal.org/project/views_navigation)

> This module adds next and previous links on content pages when
>   accessed from a view. It is intended for dynamic and/or paged view
>   results, where the result set changes according to exposed filters,
>   current user access rights,...

Answer (score 0):

Its too late to answer but you can use [flippy](https://www.drupal.org/project/flippy) module

Comment: Will this module show next/previous button pagers based on the context set by Draggable Views as Eider described?

Comment: i tried but this module can not solve sort according to draggable views,instead i created a custom module,Used the views Sql query and created my own next and previous buttons getting the nid from the query